# appending to file and messages come up in wrong order python

Tags: python, file, append

I have written a program that reads a file consisting of 10 pairs of numbers, and then divides the two, producing a mixed fraction which is then appended onto the original document. however, I want the error messages to be in the same order as the pairs. My file contains:

```
66 556
-56 78
43 76
0 5
6 5
a 4
98 76
4 2
66 54
98 21
```

and my program looks like this:

```
from fractions import gcd     
x=0
y=0
global index
index=0
wordlist=[]
with open('topheavy.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                print(word)
                wordlist.append(word)
print (wordlist)
print (len(wordlist))
def mixedfraction():
    global index
    while index<len(wordlist):
        global x
        global y
        x=wordlist[index]
        y=wordlist[index+1]
        neg=False
        with open ('topheavy.txt','a') as g:
            try:
                float(x)
            except ValueError:
                g.write ('x is not a number.\n')
                global index
                index+=2
                mixedfraction()
            try:
                float(y)
            except ValueError:
                g.write ('y is not a number.\n')
                global index
                index+=2
                mixedfraction()      
    #the above code checks if its a  number.
        x=int(x)
        y=int(y)
        orx=0
        ory=0
        orx+=x
        ory+=y
        if x==0 or y==0:
            with open ('topheavy.txt','a') as g:
                g.write ('you cant divide by 0!\n')
                global index
                index+=2
                mixedfraction()
    #this is to make sure you dont get a divide by 0 error.
        if x<0 and not y<0:
            neg=True
            x*=-1
        elif y<0 and not x<0:
            neg=True
            y*=-1
        if 1==1:
            xy=(x//y)
            modxy=(x%y)
            modxy=round(modxy,0)
            xy=round(xy,0)
            y=round(y,0)
            xdivisor=gcd(modxy, y)
            modxy//=xdivisor
            y//=xdivisor
    #the above 3 lines reduce the fraction, as do the similar 3 lines in the other bit of code.
            with open ('topheavy.txt','a') as g:
                if modxy!=0 and xy!=0: 
                    b= ('{}/{}={} and {}/{}\n'.format(orx,ory,xy, modxy, y  ))
                    if neg==True:
                        b=(' {}/{}=-{} and {}/{}\n'.format(orx,ory,xy, modxy, y  ))
                    g.write (b)
                elif modxy==0 and xy!=0:     
                    b= ('{}/{}={} \n'.format(orx,ory,xy))
                    if neg==True:
                        b=(' {}/{}=-{} \n'.format(orx,ory,xy))
                    g.write (b)
                elif xy==0:         
                    b=('{}/{}={}/{} \n'.format(orx,ory,modxy, y))
                    if neg==True:
                        b=('{}/{}=-{}/{} \n'.format(orx,ory,modxy, y))
                    g.write (b)
    #this if clause stops the program from saying '5 and 0/5' or a similar thing.
        global index
        index=index+2
mixedfraction()
```

when I run it, I get this:

```
66 556
-56 78
43 76
0 5
6 5
a 4
98 76
4 2
66 54
98 2166/556=33/278 
-56/78=-28/39 
43/76=43/76 
6/5=1 and 1/5
98/76=1 and 11/38
4/2=2 
66/54=1 and 2/9
98/21=4 and 2/3
x is not a number.
98/3=32 and 2/3
you cant divide by 0!
0/5=32 and 2/3
```

the 'you cant divide by 0' message is in the wrong place, and so is the 'x is not a number' message. I dont know how to get them to go in the right places. Then it adds some weird random line at the end, which should not be there. I have looked all over and cant find a solution. Thanks for any help.

What I want is:

```
66 556
-56 78
43 76
0 5
6 5
a 4
98 76
4 2
66 54
66/556=answer
-56/78=answer
43/76=answer
you cant divide by 0!
6/5=answer
x is not a number!
98/76=answer
4/2= answer
66/54=answer
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're expect.

Comment: Why you can't divide 0\5? You can't divide only in case of 5\0.

Comment: yeah sorry, i meant 5/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script gets following data from the file:

```
66 556
-56 78
43 76
0 5
6 5
a 4
98 76
4 2
66 54
98 21
```

and saves computed data to the same file:

```
66 556
-56 78
43 76
0 5
6 5
a 4
98 76
4 2
66 54
98 21

66 / 556 = 33/278
-56 / 78 = -28/39
43 / 76 = 43/76
0 / 5 = 0
6 / 5 = 6/5
a / 4 = Not a number!
98 / 76 = 49/38
4 / 2 = 2
66 / 54 = 11/9
98 / 21 = 14/3
```

Here is the Python script:

```
from fractions import Fraction
file = 'topheavy.txt'
outputStr = ''
flag = True

with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                if (flag):
                    dividend = word
                    flag = False
                else:
                    divisor = word
                    try:
                        fraction = Fraction(int(dividend), int(divisor))
                    except ZeroDivisionError:
                        fraction = "You can't divide by 0!"
                    except:
                        fraction = "Not a number!"
                    string = dividend + " / " + divisor + " = " + str(fraction) + "\n"
                    outputStr += string
                    flag = True

f = open(file, 'a')
f.write("\n\n" + outputStr)
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks so much! how would i get that to show mixed fractions?

Comment: I changed my script to calculate fractions.